# How to dynamically change focus from one field to next field on custombutton click with react redux form field

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I want to dynamically change the focus from one field to next field on custom button click in react redux form field.

Below is the code:

Defined outside the class

```
const FormTextInput = props =>
(<TextInput
  {...props}
  ref={props.ref}
  multiline={props.multiline}
  maxLength={props.maxLength}
  autoFocus={props.autoFocus}
  value={props.input.value}
  onChangeText={props.input.onChange}
  keyboardType={props.keyboardType}
  autoCorrect={false}
  onEndEditing={() => {
    if (props.onEndEditing) {
      props.onEndEditing();
    }
    if (props.input.onEndEditing) {
      props.input.onEndEditing();
    }
  }}
/>);
```

Below is where the above component is passed as in field component

Defined inside the class

```
        <Field
            autoFocus
            multiline={false}
            maxLength={75}
            component={FormTextInput}
            name={'firstName'}
            label={'First Name *'}
            autocapitalize={'words'}
        />
        <Field
            multiline={false}
            maxLength={75}
            component={FormTextInput}
            name={'lastName'}
            label={'Last Name *'}
            autocapitalize={'words'}
        />
```